# Oracle APEX filter query on page item

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have the following `WHERE` clause in my query:

```
 START_DATE=SYSDATE-:P1_NUM_OF_DAYS
```

how can I change my where clause to return ALL the records when P1_NUM_OF_DAYS is NULL?

Comment: Isn't this same as this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806671/oracle-apex-adding-a-conditional-filter-to-a-query

Comment: @Blurryface, no, it is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you should rather use `trunc(sysdate)` than pure `sysdate` (which contains time component).

Anyway, here you go:

```
where start_date = case when :P1_NUM_OF_DAYS is null then start_date
                        else trunc(sysdate) - :P1_NUM_OF_DAYS
                   end
```